# Change Firebase Firestore Server location

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to change the location of the server for example to Frankfurt Europe? I've already created the project and either by incident or through the unusable formula in Android studio selected the us as a the server location.

If you can't change it afterwards, is it possible to download all data and upload it to a new project with a different server location but otherwise same configuration?